# Create a 3 value checkbutton on SWT (unspecified, yes, no)

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to create a checkbutton in SWT but the SWT.CHECK only has two values: marked or unmarked.

I'd like my checkbox to have three values: unspecified, yes and no. yes would be a V mark and no would be a X mark.

How should I go about doing that? Should I create a regular button that (when clicked) changes the text inside and create a circular beaviour to change from nil->v->x->nil->... ?

thank you

Comment: @Rüdiger-Herrmann while that did point me to the right direction, it was not what I asked for.. The greyed check is not the same as a "no" and would be confusing. I modified your anwser to use images, but still not sure if it is the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SWT snippets have an example fora tri-state button:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet293.java

With a selection listener like the one below it iterate over the states grayed, checked and unchecked when selected.

```
button.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
  private int state;
  public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent event ) {
    state++;
    if( state > 2 ) {
      state = 0;
    }
    Button button = ( Button )event.widget;
    switch( state ) {
      case 0:
        button.setSelection( false );
        button.setGrayed( false );
      break;
      case 1:
        button.setSelection( true );
        button.setGrayed( false );
      break;
      case 2:
        button.setSelection( true );
        button.setGrayed( true );
      break;
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! while that did point me to the right direction, it was not what I asked for.. The greyed check is not the same as a "no" and would be confusing. I modified your anwser to use images, but still not sure if it is the best solution. 
[modified code here](http://pastebin.com/t11hJymQ)

Comment: The grayed state usually stand for 'undefined' or 'unknown'. If you mean 'best solution' from a usability POV it certainly depends on your use case. While it is uncommon to use a regular button to switch between three states ir might make sense in this very case. Alternatively a group of (radio) buttons might fit as well.

Comment: I usually see the grayed state being used in a tree of checkboxes. If some, but not all, childs of a tree node are selected, the tree node is grayed. The expected behaviour is to click on the tree node to select every child (transforming into a 'checked' state) and click again to transform into a blank state.

Comment: this snippet demonstrates what I tried to explain: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet274.java

Comment: *If some, but not all, childs of a tree node are selected ..." == mixed-state/unspecified. It is unfortunate that the SWT method `setGrayed()` is named after one possible presentation, rather than the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can inherit from the button class. Butt this class is final. That's the reason why inherit here dosen't work.
You can define a class with a button as a local variable. In the constructor you create the Button. The Constructer of your Class musst have the same variablen as the Button class. Normaly the composite and the intStyle.
Then you can add more properties to the button like the third state.
When you need the button in the surface, than you can get him from a property.
Note it's quick and dirty. When you work clean, you doesn't give the button back. Then you have to write the functions and properties of the button in your class. So far it's a lot of work, because you haven't inherit. But you can do something like this.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class MyThreeStateButton {
private int intStateLoc;
private Button buttonLoc;

    public MyThreeStateButton(Composite comParentIn, int intStyleIn) {

    buttonLoc = new Button(comParentIn, intStyleIn);

    intStateLoc= 0;
    buttonLoc.setSelection(true);
    buttonLoc.setGrayed(false);

    buttonLoc.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            workState();

        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

public Button getButton() {
    return buttonLoc;
}

public int getState() {
    return intStateLoc;
}

public void setState(int intStateIn) {
    intStateLoc= intStateIn-1;
    workState();
}

private void workState() {

    intStateLoc++;

    if (intStateLoc>2) {
        intStateLoc=0;
    }

    switch (intStateLoc) {

        case 0:
            buttonLoc.setSelection(true);
            buttonLoc.setGrayed(false);
            break;

        case 1:
            buttonLoc.setSelection(false);
            buttonLoc.setGrayed(false);
            break;

        case 2:
            buttonLoc.setSelection(true);
            buttonLoc.setGrayed(true);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: At the beginning i thought it is quick and dirty giving back the button. Now i'm convinced that it must giving back, because you have interfaces of this object-type(and your Object is not of the type button). I know it is not fine, because you can change the look of the Button at another point of your code. And so you can wirte code that is hard to maintainable.But it does not seem to be changeable.